# How do I change the width of my dropdown bubble?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following html and css which creates a popped out menu on a click of a button. I want to be able to change the width of the bubble, how can I do this?

This is how the dropdown bubble looks like: http://puu.sh/8St3e.png

[screenshot http://puu.sh/8St3e.png](http://puu.sh/8St3e.png)

```
<div class="dropdown" style="display:inline">
    <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="pops" >Select Populations</button>
    <ul id="popupDropDown" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" width="500px">    
    </ul>
</div>


.dropdown-menu:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: '';
}

.dropdown-menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle instead of the image?

Comment: UL has hardcoded with of 500px. Should be removed. Then you can add .dropdown-menu .li { white-space: nowrap }. This might solve your problem as each item in the list will now use what width it needs. A bit hard to verify though without a fiddle....

Comment: Okay, I see where you are going with this. I have a set of input and label tags which are listen in the bubble. I just found out that the ubble actually changes with depending on the content, but as you can see on the picture "complex ab.karyotype" is pushed down. So do I keep both input and label on the same line? I've tried using display:inline, but it doesn't do anything. <input bla bla/> (here there is created a line break, which I don't want) <label bla bla/>

Comment: I have a fiddle here where I do the same except on a link, and it doesn't create a new line.. http://jsfiddle.net/kq5Ef/85/

Comment: Here's a fiddle of it. http://jsfiddle.net/kq5Ef/85/
My confusion however is that in this example, the bubble expands, on my actual website, it doesn't when I have both input and label.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove this inline style from the `<ul id="popupDropDown" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" width="500px">` so that it is as follows:

```
<ul id="popupDropDown" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
```

Then you can set the width in css or (better) leave it without a width to let it flex with the content.

Comment: It looks like the there may be further styles on your input causing the label to drop a line. If your input is float:left;display:block; then changing your label from 'inline-block' to 'block' and then back again reproduces the issue. Without seeing the full effect of inherited styles it is hard to debug any further. Hope that gives you some clues.